# Error E0289: No instance of constructor "Movie::Movie" matches the argument list for a Basic Program (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have no idea why I'm getting this error on this basic program. I even checked the code and searched this site and Google for answers. I don't understand how to fix my error though.

LINKS:
[E0289 : No instance of constructor "Phone::Phone" matches the argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720171/e0289-no-instance-of-constructor-phonephone-matches-the-argument-list)
[no instance of constructor matches the argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457483/no-instance-of-constructor-matches-the-argument-list)
[Error: No instance of constructor matches the argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479200/error-no-instance-of-constructor-matches-the-argument-list)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "trimdecimal.h"

using namespace std;

class Movie {
    public:
        string title;
        string director;
        string mainCast1;
        string mainCast2;
        int yearReleased;
        bool isAHit;
        int publicLikePercentage;
};

int main()
{
    Movie movie1 = Movie("Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw", "David Leitch", "Dwayne Johnson", "Jason Statham", 2019, true, 89);
}
```

And I am getting this error as I stated in the title:

```
E0289     no instance of constructor "Movie::Movie" matches the argument list
```

I coded this on Visual Studio 2019

Any solutions? I will wholeheartedly appreciate any fixes but please be specific and explain to me how to solve it like how you'd do to a child.

Comment: Where do you have a constructor that accepts 7 values as arguments? Actually, where have you defined any constructor at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined a constructor for your `Movie` class that takes those values as parameters.

If you're trying to just initialize the object by members, use `{}` instead of `()`:

```cpp
Movie movie1 = Movie{"Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw", "David Leitch", "Dwayne Johnson", "Jason Statham", 2019, true, 89};
```

or just

```cpp
Movie movie1 = {"Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw", "David Leitch", "Dwayne Johnson", "Jason Statham", 2019, true, 89};
```